# What's the difference between get_the_time and get_the_date?

Tags: date-time

Both function returns date and time. What's the difference between them? Do you have any example? Thanks.

Comment: The real question for me is why is the template tag called "the_time()" but the "get" version is "get_the_date()"!?

Answer (score 10):

They are, very similar but with some nuances:

```
function get_the_date( $d = '' ) {
    global $post;
    $the_date = '';

    if ( '' == $d )
        $the_date .= mysql2date(get_option('date_format'), $post->post_date);
    else
        $the_date .= mysql2date($d, $post->post_date);

    return apply_filters('get_the_date', $the_date, $d);
}

function get_the_time( $d = '', $post = null ) {
    $post = get_post($post);

    if ( '' == $d )
        $the_time = get_post_time(get_option('time_format'), false, $post, true);
    else
        $the_time = get_post_time($d, false, $post, true);
    return apply_filters('get_the_time', $the_time, $d, $post);
}
```

1. `get_the_date()` always works for current global `$post`,  `get_the_time()` allows you to specify post as argument.
2. They default to different formats, stored in `date_format` and `time_format` options respectively.
3. They pass output through different filters `get_the_date` and `get_the_time` plus lower level `get_post_time` respectively.

Comment: +1 for quoting source code. Why guess what's going on under the hood when you can take a look.

Answer (score 3):

The `the_date()` template tag only outputs the post date once per occurrence; thus, if two or more posts have the same post date, that date is only output at its first occurrence in the Loop. The `the_time()` template tag outputs the post time (using any valid date/time string), as per normal.

The `get_the_date()` and `get_the_time()` template tags, however, are essentially the same. They are used to return the respective value for `the_date()` and `the_time()`. [As per the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date):

> Unlike [`the_date()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_date) this tag will **always return** the date. Modify output with 'get_the_date' filter.

So, the difference lies not in the `get_the_*()` template tags themselves, but in the `the_*()` template tags that use them.